# How to get the parent path of a given path?

Tags: vimscript

As title. For example if I have this:

```
foo/bar/baz/bee
```

which is stored in a variable, then which function should I call to get:

```
foo/bar/baz
```

Notice that I will need to store this result back to the variable.

Thanks in advance! I also want to know whether this is possible in Lua too.

Answer (score 2):

This is `fnamemodify(var, ':h')`.

Answer (score 0):

I put my self-answer here since I've dived into my problem and solved it before I saw the answer post here.

This is a workaround, in Lua:

```lua
local raw_path = 'foo/bar/baz/bee'
vim.cmd('cd '..raw_path..'/../')
local result = vim.fn.getcwd() -- normalized.
vim.cmd('cd -') -- restore.
```